# how to overwrite or empty a Parse PFRelation

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, relation

I have a problem with updating an existing Parse object with Relation, where i would like to replace an existing relation with a new list of objects. Unfortunately there is no removeAllObjects in PFRelation.

```
    PFRelation *buddies = [invitation relationForKey:@"buddies"];

    // here i need to remove all existing objects in the relation
    // eg: [buddies removeAllObjects];

    // new invites
    for (PFProfile *buddy in self.selectedBuddies) {
        [buddies addObject:buddy];
    }
```

What are the correct ways to clear objects in relation, or create a new relation and replace the current one?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know of is to do this:

```
PFRelation *buddies = [invitation relationForKey:@"buddies"];

PFQuery *query = [buddies query];
NSArray *array = [query findObjects];
for(PFObject *object in array)
{
   [buddies removeObject:object];

}
```

I don't know if you're using PFObjects or PFUsers for "buddies," so you may need to modify the code a little.

Comment: @DaddycatTanYinSee Oh I'm sorry! Totally forgot lol. Let me edit my answer, I just thought of another way to do this...

Comment: thanks, that's what i thought of too but i think int is inefficient, i am looking at how to do this without querying the existing relation objects.

Comment: @DaddycatTanYinSee It doesn't look like this is possible: https://www.parse.com/questions/a-removeallobjects-method-for-a-pfrelation you can try emailing parse to ask them to implement it, though.